# How to make discord.py bot run forever if client.run() returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

**Problem**

My discord.py bot's client.run() is returning unexpectedly every few days or so followed by an error "Task was destroyed but it is pending!".

**Question**

Why is client.run() returning at all? And how can I change my bot to properly handle this issue and run forever?

**Code (stripped out a lot to keep it simple for discussion):**

```
import asyncio
import discord

TOKEN = 'my bot token goes here'
CHANNEL_ID = 'my channel id goes here'

async def DiscordMsgSendTask():

  await client.wait_until_ready()
  my_channel = discord.Object(id=CHANNEL_ID)

  while not client.is_closed:

    # wait a bit to prevent busy loop
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    # check for and handle new event here

    # if an event was handled then send a message to the channel
    embed = discord.Embed(description='Event was handled')
    await client.send_message(my_channel, embed=embed)

client = discord.Client()

while True:
  client.loop.create_task(DiscordMsgSendTask())

  try:
    client.run(TOKEN)
  except Exception as e:
    logging.warning('Exception: ' + str(e))

  client = discord.Client()
```

**Additional Info**

The bot's purpose is basically just to check for a new file in a specific directory, and then send a message to a specific discord channel to report it. This only occurs around 10 times a day, so the bot's traffic is extremely low.

In an attempt to make the bot tolerate errors/disconnects, I put it into the while True loop, which may be wrong approach.

Using Python 3.6.5 and Discord.py 0.16.12

**Edit - Added traceback**

Adding traceback from a previous failure earlier in the day.

```
2018-06-20 04:33:08 [ERROR] Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.run() done, defined at /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py:428> exception=ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 434, in run
    msg = yield from self.read_message()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 456, in read_message
    frame = yield from self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 511, in read_data_frame
    frame = yield from self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 546, in read_frame
    self.reader.readexactly, is_masked, max_size=max_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/framing.py", line 86, in read_frame
    data = yield from reader(2)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/streams.py", line 674, in readexactly
    yield from self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/streams.py", line 464, in _wait_for_data
    yield from self._waiter
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 723, in _read_ready
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
2018-06-20 04:33:08 [ERROR] Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<DiscordMsgSendTask() running at /home/bot.py:119> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc99bfd7a68>()]>>
2018-06-20 04:33:08 [ERROR] Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fc999b59240>
```

Comment: Are you sure that "Task was destroyed but it is pending!" was the exact error message? I think there should be more traceback that comes with it.

Comment: @abccd Added more output including a traceback

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use the pre-defined `run` method since that only handles `KeyboardInterrupt`. You will need to create a exit strategy that closes all tasks while still leaving the loop running.

The following example will raise `SystemExit` (to simulate your unexpected fatal error (The RST - ConnectionError error)) when a message "die" is received by the bot. The `SystemExit` will get "caught" and restarts your bot. Upon `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised, the bot will exit successfully without error.

```
import asyncio
import discord

TOKEN = 'TOKEN_HERE'
client = discord.Client()


async def task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('Running')


def handle_exit():
    print("Handling")
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.logout())
    # For python 3.9, use asyncio.all_tasks instead
    for t in asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=client.loop):
        if t.done():
            t.exception()
            continue
        t.cancel()
        try:
            client.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(t, 5, loop=client.loop))
            t.exception()
        except (asyncio.InvalidStateError, asyncio.TimeoutError, asyncio.CancelledError):
            pass


while True:
    @client.event
    async def on_message(m):
        if m.content == 'die':
            print("Terminating")
            raise SystemExit

    client.loop.create_task(task())
    try:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(client.start(TOKEN))
    except SystemExit:
        handle_exit()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        handle_exit()
        client.loop.close()
        print("Program ended")
        break
    
    print("Bot restarting")
    client = discord.Client(loop=client.loop)
```

---

In Discord (someone types `die`):

```
die
```

In terminal (STDOUT):

```
Running
Running
Running
Terminating
Handling
Bot restarting
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
<CTRL-C> (KeyboardInterrupt)
Handling
Program ended
```

---

Side note:

If you're still confused about your error, it's not your code to blame. Errno 104 is a server side fatal error that's usually unpreventable by the end users.

Comment: It works and keep the bot running, but when I try to test the "die" message it raises an exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\main.py", line 126, in <module>
    handle_exit()
  File "C:\python\main.py", line 31, in handle_exit
    for t in asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=client.loop):
AttributeError: type object '_asyncio.Task' has no attribute 'all_tasks'

Comment: @Windgate Hey, it's because you're using py 3.9, `asyncio.Task.all_tasks` has been moved to `asyncio.all_tasks`

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAH today I tried with asyncio.all_tasks and it runs well, but had another errors while running, I will try to test again and comment here, thanks for all dude