# Python Bot keep running forever

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How to keep my bot running forever if bot crashes anytime.

I running this **main.py** file in `screen` using `putty` on linux server but i need to run another file to check this main.py file running or not every 30 minutes if not it should restart main.py file.

so below is my **main.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print (bot.user.name)
    print (bot.user.id)
    print ("_____")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def first(ctx):
     await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))

bot.run("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: My answer solves this problem in a more generic way. If your problem involves a discord bot, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981577/8746648) provides a much better solution.**

---

**Original answer:**

You can wrap the call to your program into a bash script. Here an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  sleep 0.5
  ./bot # your program
  echo "[$(date)] bot exited with code $?. restarting ..."
done
```

The script above would restart your program whenever it exits. But if I was you, i would include a check that stops restarting your script if it crashes constantly.

```
#!/bin/bash

FAILS=0

while true
do
  sleep 0.5
  ./bot # your program
  EXIT=$?
  ((FAILS++))

  if [[ $FAILS -gt 10 ]]
  then
    echo "[$(date)] failed to many times. aborting ..."
    exit 1
  fi

  echo "[$(date)] bot exited with code $EXIT. restarting ..."

done
```

Comment: Ok thanks got it.  and one last question like `main.py` crashes is there a chance to crash `runforever.sh`  sorry for a dumb question.

Comment: I have a problem now. bot won't quitting i tried `CTRL C` i getting a message `bot exited with code 0. restarting ...`  and bot restarts suddenly.

Comment: got solution so i can fix this ?

Comment: Ok so now it stops only 5 seconds and starts again.  So it won't able to stop permanently right.